# Problema al realizar consulta MySQL en múltiples tablas

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, subconsultas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo un problema, resulta que tengo dos tablas en MySQL, una de empleados y una de los movimientos que ha tenido ese empleado, en la primera tabla está el id y nombre del contacto, en la segunda el id del movimiento, la fecha del movimiento y su nueva área, mi objetivo es tener una sentencia SQL para obtener una lista de todos los contactos con su respectiva área actual. Tengo el SQL que pongo a continuación y funciona bien, el problema es que son muchos SELECT y siento que el servidor se satura, la pregunta sería, es posible realizar la misma operación de otra manera?

```
SELECT 
contactos.Id_Contacto as 'IdContacto', 
concat(contactos.Nombres, ' ', contactos.Apellido_Paterno,' ', contactos.Apellido_Materno) as 'Nombre',
(SELECT movimientos_personal.Id_Movimiento FROM bd_secjo.movimientos_personal 
where movimientos_personal.Id_Empleado = IdContacto order by Fecha_Inicio desc limit 1) as 'UltMovimiento',
(SELECT movimientos_personal.Nombre_Adscripcion_Nueva FROM bd_secjo.movimientos_personal 
where movimientos_personal.Id_Movimiento = UltMovimiento) as 'Adscripcion',
(SELECT movimientos_personal.Fecha_Inicio FROM bd_secjo.movimientos_personal 
where movimientos_personal.Id_Movimiento = UltMovimiento) as 'FechaAdscripcion'
FROM bd_secjo.contactos;
```

Comment: Una gran disculpa, no supe la forma correcta de poner primero el texto y luego la imagen.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el resultado que obtienes contra el esperado? o ¿qué consideras que hay que corregir con tu query?

Comment: El resultado es bueno, obtengo lo que necesito, es decir extraigo el ultimo movimiento que tuvo un empleado basandome en la fecha, el problema que considero es que son demasiados select, ahí todavía me falta agregar otras columnas y en total van a ser como siete select en una misma consulta algo muy pesado para el servidor.

Comment: Sin la estructura de las tablas es difícil determinar cómo se puede simplificar esa consulta. Mientras tanto solo se puede simplificar hasta este punto:

Comment: `SELECT 
 C.Id_Contacto as 'IdContacto', 
 CONCAT(C.Nombres, ' ', C.Apellido_Paterno,' ', C.Apellido_Materno) AS 'Nombre',
 (SELECT MPP.Id_Movimiento FROM bd_secjo.movimientos_personal MP WHERE MPP.Id_Empleado = IdContacto ORDER BY Fecha_Inicio desc LIMIT 1) as 'UltMovimiento',
 MP.Nombre_Adscripcion_Nueva AS 'Adscripcion',
 MP.Fecha_Inicio AS 'FechaAdscripcion'
FROM bd_secjo.contactos C
 INNER JOIN bd_secjo.movimientos_personal MP
  ON C.UltMovimiento = MP.Id_Movimiento`

Comment: Perdón la ignoracion Phi, que significa MPP, MP y C, me bota error, dice columna desconocida MPP

Comment: Es un alias a la tabla para que no tengas que poner el nombre completo cuando haces referencia a un campo de esa tabla. Por ejemplo `MP` es el alias de la tabla `movimientos_personal`, entonces cuando hagas referencia a un campo solo lo llamas así: `MP.Fecha_Inicio`